# How to fix error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Tags: php, laravel

I have an input to enter the tags. Each course will have many tags and I want to save these tags in the same column.

Input

```html
    <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 box-shadow-1 mt-1">
        <h4 class="content-header-title"> Tags </h4>
            <select name="tags[]" data-tags="true" id="tags" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

Srcipt select2

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#tags').select2({
        placeholder: "Tags",
        tags: true
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Controller

```php
    function save(Request $request)
    {
        $lesson = new Lesson;
        $lesson->tags= $request->input('tags');
        $lesson->content = $request->content;
        $lesson->save();
        return redirect(url('admin/lessons/edit'))->with('message', 'Successful');
    }
```

But when i click to save it appears an error like this:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Xampp-install\htdocs\eduwebsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 869

Comment: What type of column is your `tags` column in the `lessons` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tags` input is an array of values, so you cannot just store a php array into a database column.

If your `tags` is a `varchar` in your database, then try to `implode` the elements into a string:

```
$lesson->tags= implode(', ', $request->input('tags'));
```

This will store it as a comma separated list of values: programming, tech .. so on, whatever your tags are.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to store tags as array in database you can use serialize

```
$lesson->tags= serialize($request->tags);
```

or better way is using **[Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)**

```
class Lesson extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'tags' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `tags` as array in your input . Now when you are trying to save it in controller you are trying to put array in database

```
$lesson->tags= $request->input('tags');
```

in this line. that's why the error. you should try to save it like this .

```
$lesson->tags= json_encode( $request->input('tags') );
```

Comment: if i use json_encode it'll save like this ["tag1","tag2"]. But I want to save it like text. Example: tag1,tag2

Comment: then you can  use `implode()` function . it will convert the array to plain string. also it works when don't have nested arrays. for nested arrays it is better to use `json_encode`